# Geany: Possible to automatically enable/disable line wrap dependent on file type?

Tags: text-processing, text, editors, programming, geany

In [Geany](https://geany.org) text editor / IDE, is there a way to tell it to automatically enable **line wrapping** for certain file types, but not for others?

For example, for `.txt` files, I would like it to always enable **line wrapping**, but for `.c` and `.asm` files, I do not want **line wrapping** enabled.

Comment: it seems to me that filedefs don't allow this https://www.geany.org/manual/#filetype-definition-files , thus it would have to be a plugin to set [geany] line_wrapping=true or false, which is hopefully doable

Comment: what *is* definitely possible is to set `line_wrap_visuals` and `line_wrap_indent` to alter the appearance of the wrapping